# How did the Lunar module reached orbit speed?

Tags: the-moon, orbit, lunar-module, lunar-orbit

How does the lunar module of Apollo 11 reached an orbit speed of 1600 meter/second in order to rejoin the CSM (Command/Service Module)?

Additional question, Where are the Oxygen & Fuel tanks of the module and what kind of such small engine was used to reach that speed? is there a schema / specification of the lunar module we can look?

[image: Lunar Module]

Comment: The speed required to be in a low circular orbit around the Moon isn't 1600 miles per second. It's about 1600 _meters_ per second. 1600 miles per second is more than four times escape velocity from the surface of the Sun.

Comment: @notovny thanks, fixed

Comment: Apollo Lunar Module didn't use oxygen for propulsion.  It used hydrazine mix and dinitrogen tetroxide. They have significant advantages if you need 1) to store fuel in tanks for many days (or even years!) 2) to start engines many times. Both the substances are liquid at ambient temperature (liquid oxygen requires very low temperature). Also they ignite just in contact - so the engine construction is simple. Downsides - they are toxic, and have some lower exaust velocity.

Answer (score 6):

Addressing

> How does the lunar module of Apollo 11 reached an orbit speed of 1600 meter/second in order to rejoin the CSM (Command/Service Module)?

This table from [APOLLO EXPERIENCE REPORT -
MISSION PLANNING FOR LUNAR MODULE
DESCENT AND ASCENT](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/HSI-45202.r.pdf) by my former colleague Floyd Bennett shows the delta-v requirements for the Apollo 11 ascent to be 6055.7 feet per second and that the Lunar Module Ascent Engine had plenty of performance to make it with the propellant load on board.

[image]

For detailed information on the ascent propulsion system, please consult the Experience Report [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19730010173).

Addressing

> Where are the Oxygen & Fuel tanks of the module? is there a schema / specification of the lunar module we can look?

[image]

From the Air and Space Museum [website](https://airandspace.si.edu/multimedia-gallery/5211640jpg).

Comment: Thanks! looks super small though, still wonder how it got into orbit speed with that amount of fuel. what type of engine was it so it can reach that speed? (even with no air fraction).

Comment: @RoeeYossef see this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29862/6944

Comment: In addition to the excellent link in the comment above, weight was ruthlessly shaved from the ascent module.  The thinnest possible wires were used; so thin that breaking wires were a concern during development.  Paneling is so thin that it appears flimsy in photos... because it is _just_ enough to get the job done.  And so on.

Comment: @WayneConrad so what type of engine was used to reach such speed in 1969?

Comment: @RoeeYossef The ascent engine was liquid fueled, bipropellant, hypergolic, non-cryogenic, fixed thrust, non-gimballed, and pressure fed.  Other types of engine perform better, but it was optimized for reliability first and performance second.

Comment: Beyond just that the lunar module was very lightly built; a pair of big tanks full of fuel are *pretty heavy* compared to that fairly small, entirely hollow lunar module with no heavy cargo other than the astronauts themselves. The engine is an ordinary hypergolic powered engine, it is nothing special.

Answer (score 4):

How did they reach 1600 m/s:

1. the dry weight of the LM ascent module was only [2150 kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module#Ascent_stage). The propellant mass was 2350 kg, so slightly over 50% of the ascent module weight was propellant.
2. this weight was launched from the moon, in 1/6 g gravity.

The [Tsiolkovsly rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) allows us to calculate which speed we can achieve with these numbers.

$$\Delta v = v_\text{e} \ln \frac{m_0}{m_f} = I_\text{sp} g_0 \ln \frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

- $v_\text{e}$ is the effective exhaust velocity;
- $I_\text{sp}$ is the specific impulse in dimension of time: 311 s
- $g_0$ is the gravitational constant: 9.8 m/s2
- $\ln$ is the natural logarithm
- $m_0$ is the initial total mass, including propellant and payload, a.k.a. wet mass; 4700 kg
- $m_f$ is the final total mass without propellant,a.k.a. dry mass; 2150 kg

So 311 * 9.8 * ln(4500/2150) is 2383 m/s of delta-V is available, far more than the 1600 m/s we need.

This ignores gravity losses, which will reduce the available delta-v.

[Approximation of gravity losses](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37568/how-do-you-calculate-gravity-loss-simplified): burn time (465 s) * gravity (1.6 m/s2) is 744 m/s, 2383-744 is 1640 m/s.

Comment: not so much an approximation of gravity losses, as a worst case